# Akka ZeroMQ - Any way to get the socket address?

Tags: sockets, scala, port, akka, zeromq

Let's assume the following piece of code:

```
class MQActor extends Actor {

    // Bind on port 0... Technically this should pick a free port
    val pubSocket = context.system.newSocket(SocketType.Pub, Bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:0"))

    def receive = {
        // ...
    }

}
```

My questions are:

1) Is it correct to specify port 0 to ask for a socket on any available port?

2) Assuming 1) works, how can I know which port the socket was bound to?

3) If 1) doesn't work and/or 2) is impossible, how can I bind to any available port?

Thanks in advance!

Billy

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this is not possible with ZMQ. You can however ask the actor for the socket options. Here are the options:

https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-zeromq/src/main/scala/akka/zeromq/ConcurrentSocketActor.scala#L85

You could determine an unused port yourself. But what exactly is your use case? Why do you need to bind a socket to a random port? How would the publishers know which port they should use?

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Basically, my application would create 1 or more MQs on the fly. It's not possible to determine this number before runtime and for security reasons, these MQs must be distinct (i.e. one single MQ doesn't work). I don't care which port they are bound to, but I would obviously need a way to query for it.

Yes, I could find an unused port myself, but I was given to understand that blocking code should not be used in the initialization of an actor and I don't know of a way to do this without iteratively trying to bind a ServerSocket until it works. Any suggestion on that?

Comment: You can use the technique shown here: https://github.com/akka/akka/commit/cb86591656629f1d69d5c2a558eab5420dd49042 We have since removed it because we found a better solution internally, but it seems the right thing for you, and AFAICT it should not block.

Comment: Brilliant solution! I did not think of it... I implemented something similar and it seems to work! I was under the impression that socket.close() was blocking, though...